# ReactJs Image Not found on production mode

Tags: reactjs

I have pushed my app on my repo.

The images are imported to the path:

```
react-blog-app/blob/gh-pages/static/media/_resized_300.353f8ae3.jpg
```

However on the page the images are not found.
The URL is pointing to

```
react-blog-app/static/media/_resized_300.353f8ae3.jpg
```

I have added 'contentBane' on config.json

```
{
  "apiEndpoint": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"   ,
  "devServer": {
  "contentBase": "./build"
}
```

}

Do you have any suggestion to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't add file-loader to `module.rules`. the code below is minimal webpack configuration for react app.

**webpack.config.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

// Plugins
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "production",
  entry: "./src/index.jsx",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  // externals: {
  //   "react-js": "React",
  //   "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
  // },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|es6|es|mjs)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.ejs",
      filename: "index.html",
      title: "My React App",
      inject: "body",
      scriptLoading: "defer",
      cache: true
    }),
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin()
  ],
  devtool: "source-map",
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    port: 8000,
    open: true
  }
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [["@babel/preset-react", { "development": true }]]
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development \"webpack-dev-server\"",
    "build": "webpack"
  }
```